# API to "Read Contract Information" to fetch stats of an ICO

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan

I'm looking at ways to read stats/variables displayed in EtherScan Contract Info by API,

For example recent ICO TAAS, I have contract Address,

[image]

https://etherscan.io/address/0xe7775a6e9bcf904eb39da2b68c5efb4f9360e08c#readContract

I have been trying to use Web3 and read variables but however, I'm getting 0 for totalSupply

Code used:

> function fetchTokenDetails(){
>    token = 
>   getTaasContractContract();
>
> token.totalSupply(function(error,result){
>       TemplateVar.set(template,"miscExtra",result);   });
>
> }
>
> function getTaasContractContract(){   abiArray =
>   [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"multiAsset","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"commitUpgrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getLatestVersion","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"},{"name":"_sender","type":"address"}],"name":"_forwardTransferFromWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"emitApprove","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"emitTransfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"recoverTokens","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"etoken2","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPendingVersionTimestamp","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"purgeUpgrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"optIn","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"}],"name":"transferFromWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_icap","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferToICAP","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_icap","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"}],"name":"transferToICAPWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sender","type":"address"}],"name":"_forwardApprove","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_icap","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"},{"name":"_sender","type":"address"}],"name":"_forwardTransferFromToICAPWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_icap","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"}],"name":"transferFromToICAPWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_icap","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFromToICAP","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"etoken2Symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPendingVersion","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_reference","type":"string"}],"name":"transferWithReference","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_etoken2","type":"address"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"}],"name":"init","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newVersion","type":"address"}],"name":"proposeUpgrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"optOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_sender","type":"address"}],"name":"getVersionFor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newVersion","type":"address"}],"name":"UpgradeProposal","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]
>   ;
>
> var addres = "0xe7775a6e9bcf904eb39da2b68c5efb4f9360e08c";   var
>   blockchain = web3.eth;   tuiContract = 
>   blockchain.contract(abiArray).at(addres);   return tuiContract; }

It has been a headache, Need some help

Answer (score 3):

Which version of web3 are you using?

Here is a working example with `web3@^1.0.0-beta.34`

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
contractAddress = '0xe7775a6e9bcf904eb39da2b68c5efb4f9360e08c';
provider = 'https://mainnet.infura.io';
const contractAbiJSON = '';//... The JSON abi

// Init
const web3 = new Web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbiJSON, contractAddress);

contract.methods.totalSupply().call().then((totalSupply) => {
  console.log(totalSupply);
});
```